# Android saving decimal data in database using greendao

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I use **`GreenDao`** as My `ORM` in **`Android`** and I want to have a **`Decimal`** column in one of my tables, but GreenDao do not have Decimal DataType.
Double and Float shown with scientific notation, But i want to show its real value.
One solution is to write a function to convert value with scientific notation to a value without notation, But I want to show my data from DataBase without conversion.

Comment: Which [SQLite data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) do you want to use?

Comment: I use GreenDao and I want to use one of [GreenDao datatypes](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/). But Float and Double show a number as scientific notation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no decimal data type in SQLite or greenDAO.

You have to format the values appropriately for display.